# Run applescript from C

Tags: c, applescript

How can I run an AppleScript from within an C commandline utility?
Googling didn't work, it only gave me *Objective*-C solutions...

**EDIT:**
Oops, I should have googled for 'run shell script C'...
Now i found the `system()` function...

Comment: I already solved my own problem... Next time I'll search better for a solution!

Comment: Why can't you use foundation in your project? Is CoreFoundation (C-based APIs) an option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the `exec` family of functions, which is safer than `system`:

```
int exitCode = execlp("osascript", "osascript", "-e", "say \"Hello World\"", NULL);
```